# How to redirect to the same php page after successfully logging

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an assignment whereby I provide an html login form on a page called `index.php` and upon entering the correct `username` and `password` you will be redirected to the same `index.php` page but now the login form will disappear and be replaced with html links to three other `php` pages.

In other words the html links are not visible before successfully logging only after. All of this happens on the same `php` page (`index.php`). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could just create a php session in the login, so when you access the page, you check if the session exists and then you can choose to show the login form or the page contents.
Also, you would always share some code in the question. What did you try so far?

Comment: what do i use to choose to show the login form if use a php session

Comment: what do you tried? share with us your tried code.

Answer (score 0):

#### First of all a brief knowledge to session variable.

1. You can Set the Session using `$_SESSION['username']="your-username-from-html-post";`
2. This is a global variable i.e. it will be available for use to all files throughout your website.
3. To delete session you can use `unset($_SESSION['username']);`
4. Session are very useful to make a login form in PHP and HTML as they provide a universal format to check if the user is logged in or not.
 By the Way- the session variable will be for your website only and for the same computer only on which user has logged in not for other computers(obviously)

#### Now your Answer

You can write in your index.php like this

```
If (isset($_SESSION['your-session-variable'])) {
echo 'YOUR LINK 1';
echo 'YOUR LINK 2';
echo 'YOUR LINK 3';
} else {
                //insert your form code here
}
```

Replace `$_SESSION['your-session-variable']` with your own Session Name
What this does is It check is the `$_SESSION` variable is set by `isset`
If answer is true it will print your links else it will print your html code!